# Check if two selected vertices are connected with edge

Tags: python, mesh

I need to check if two selected vertices are connected with edge or not,
I've tried this code but doesn't work!

```
import bpy, bmesh

def areConnected(V1, V2):
    if V2 in [x for y in [a.verts for a in V1.link_edges] for x in y if x != V1]:
        print('connected')
    else:
        print('Not')

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)


V1 = bm.edges[0].verts[0]
V2 = bm.edges[0].verts[1]

areConnected(V1, V2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "doesn't work" I don't know if you're having trouble getting it to run or if it's more of a logic issue.

You need to be in edit mode for it to run.

If it's printing "connected" every time and you're wondering why, it's always going to print connected as long as the mesh has an edge. If `edges[0]` is some edge and you delete that edge, `edges[0]` will switch to some other edge, as long as there is indeed another edge. Thus, passing `V1` and `V2` into you're `areConnected` function the way you have it will always print "connected" as long as an edge exists, so it's a bit redundant. Therefore, it makes more sense to set `V1 = bm.verts[some_num1]` and `V2 = bm.verts[some_num2]` because doing so doesn't initially require for there to be a connecting edge between the vertices in the first place.

Comment: It works now thank you, just one more question, is there a way to do the same without using bmesh ?

Comment: hi AlecDev, please do not ask additional questions in comments, because other people cannot find these questions and don't profit from answers. You may open as many questions as you like so please just do that instead of asking in comments. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method to check if the indices of 2 vertices are connected by an edge without using the `bmesh` module:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data

v1 = 1 # vertex index=1
v2 = 3 # vertex index=3

connected = False

for edge in mesh.edges:
    if {v1, v2} <= set(edge.vertices):
        connected = True
        break

print(f"Vertices {v1} & {v2} connected by edge? {connected}")
```

Comment: Thank you @Harry